# How to make multiple forms stay on top of main form, but not on top of other applications, in Delphi 7

Tags: forms, delphi, delphi-7

This is the code I'm using in my main form:

```
if not Assigned(FPerHist) then
begin
    Application.CreateForm(TFPerHist,FPerHist);
end;
FPerHist.Show;
```

I set FormStyle of FPerHist to StayOnTop.

This works for allowing multiple forms to be opening, while keeping all sub forms on top of the main form. But when the form is in a middle of loading something, or reached a checkpoint while debugging, the form stays on top of other applications.

Users find this annoying because they can't work on other things while this form is loading, and while debugging I can't switch to Delphi 7 window until I moved this application to another desktop (I'm using Windows 10).

Is there any other way for this to work on Delphi 7?

Comment: FWIW, there's no point using CreateForm for anything other than the main form. I wonder if that is part of the problem.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: it is not. `Application.CreateForm` simply instantiates the requeated Form object, assigning the `Application` as its `Owner`, and assigns the `Application. MainForm` if not already set. Otherwise, it has no other effect on the Form's behavior.

Comment: It's still pointless for everything other than the main form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This was solved in later Delphi versions by the introduction of the `TForm.PopupParent` property.  You would simply remove the `fsStayOnTop` style, and set the MainForm as the `PopupParent` of your secondary Forms.

But, `PopupParent` does not exist in Delphi 7, so you will have to simulate it manually, by overriding the virtual `CreateParams()` method of your secondary Forms to assign the `MainForm.Handle` as the `TCreateParams.WndParent`.

Comment: By default, WndParent should be set to be the main form so there must be something else. Still, the design was flaky and it doesn't hurt to force matters.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: IIRC (can check tomorrow), the `MainForm` window is not the default `WndParent` in D7, the `Application` window is. Window ownership was rewritten when `Application.MainFormOnTaskbar` was introduced in D2007

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly. It looks tedious because I have 100+ forms but I can even use this on a template form.

Comment: You are right about `WndParent`. I must be remembering how things worked in my old D6 code base and I guess I already fixed this issue.

Comment: By itself this works, but is not entirely reliable since Windows XP, as the secondary forms occasionally stay in front of other applications when switching. To fully simulate the `PopupParent`, you need to add `Params.Style := Params.Style or WS_POPUP;`. However, even that seems to work more reliably by avoiding the form's `Show` method and setting `.Visible` true or false instead.

Comment: @GarthThornton: `TCustomForm.CreateParams()` already enables `WS_POPUP` if `BorderStyle` is `bsNone` and `Parent(Window)` are `nil`/`0`, or `BorderStyle` is `bsDialog`.  And `TCustomForm.Show()` sets `Visible := True`, but it also calls `TControl.BringToFront()`, which ultimately invokes `SetWindowPos(HWND_TOP)`, but that should not make the Form window appear on top of other apps, especially when switching between apps. Only `HWND_TOPMOST` can do that.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: true, and subforms aren't always bsDialog; my main D7 project has some that are `bsSizeToolWin`. The issue with switching forms seems to be due to Windows XP and later switching to what it thinks is the main form, which can disrupt what should happen with the Z order. This is probably only an issue in apps with sibling forms, which this project also has; in which case there's no problem using `Show` with a single main form.